# English-Language Grammar/English-language Grammar(titles)

Tags: capitalization

I tried to find more rules on correct title hyphenation, but my question hasn't gotten its answer yet.

Do we hyphenate the compound adjectives that are not the first adjectives of a compond adjective? That's a title that I don't know how to hyphenate right.

1. English-Language Grammar
2. English-language Grammar

Comment: Are you asking about the hyphen or capitalizing Language? *In titles*, do we *capitalize* the second *word* of compound adjectives?

Comment: I'm asking about whether to capitalize *Language* or not.

Comment: It's part of a compound adjective, which is considered a single word as far as I remember, so I'm in doubt.

Comment: Your question asks about hyphenation, not caps.

Comment: As Yosef Baskin has indicated, your question is unclear.
Your question asks "Do we ++hyphenate++ the compound adjectives"
But your comment above stated "I'm asking about whether to ++capitalize++ Language or not".
Please clarify your question!
It is also quite possible that British & American differ from one another!  Are you asking about either of those variations in particular?

Comment: The rules for both English capitalization and punctuation are unclear and unreasonable (not to mention difficult to find), so the correct solution is the one most commonly chosen: Do what you please, since everybody else does it, too. Just continue to maintain that yours is the correct choice, despite the others who don't know better. After all, nobody cares except silly old grammar teachers.

Comment: I have failed to write my question right. I want to know whether to CAPITALIZE  *Language* or not. I do believe that the compound adjective written with that word is definitely correct.